# No valid SSL certificate shown on browser for download attachment response type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have deployed a Spring boot web application with REST API endpoint like /download/{pathparam1}/{pathparam2} in tomcat with server.xml configuration as this -

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/opt/production/app/tomcat/ssl/someorgname.pfx"
    keystoreType="PKCS12"
    keystorePass="someencryptedpassword"/>
```

The application is working fine but I cannot see a valid certificate for it in the browser for the entire API endpoint https://hostname.com:8443/**download**/{pathparam1}/{pathparam2}.

The browser however, shows a valid certificate till https://hostname.com:8443/**download**/{pathparam1} and as soon I append the second path parameter in the URL, no valid certificate can be seen.

If I try to hit https://hostname.com:8443/**downloadxyz**/{pathparam1}/{pathparam2}, the browser shows a valid certificate for it.

Do I need to make some changes at application configuration or tomcat server settings to fix this?

*The .pfx file is shared by my organization for a trusted certificate signed by Entrust.*

---

**Edit:**

Changed the connector port to 8443 in tomcat

**Update:**

After some hit and trial I have found that this isn't the issue with tomcat or any SSL configurations. But it has something to do with the API itself.

Through my REST API, I am trying to download a .cab file saved in my local server path. And I believe, this is what is causing the issue.

When I try to download a .txt file, then the SSL cert comes as valid, but when I try downloading .cab/.zip/.csv/.xls file, SSL cert appears to be invalid in the browser.

**Final Observation:**

1. I could conclude that for any endpoint which serves a response that the browser can present inline, the browser shows a valid SSL certificate. But when an endpoint returns a downloadable attachment, the SSL certificate is shown as invalid.
2. Content-Disposition played no role in it. In both the cases, my APIs Content-Disposition was set as attachment.
3. However, apparently this hasn't caused an issue with the application. I can access the endpoint via API gateway and clients are able to consume it without any issues.

Comment: `https://hostname.com` is not your Tomcat server, which listens on port 8080 instead (so the URL will start with `https://hostname.com:8080`).

Comment: Yes, I am calling the API on 8080 port. Missed that in the question above. Have now updated.

Comment: Does your app return a redirect to the browser for the full path? Nothing else makes sense, because the cert (and key and chain) used by a server is determined before it receives the resource aka 'path' part of the URL. Unless on WIndows 10 and using its schannel build, try `curl -v https://hostname:8080/fullpath` (if your root cert is not in curl's default truststore add `--cacert file` or `capath dir`).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Thanks for your comment, I have added an update in my question. Seems like, the issue is with the API which is trying to download a .zip/.cab file from local server path.

Comment: I observed that valid certificate is not shown on top of the browser beside address bar for the API endpoints which stream the response as an attachment. Someone can share more on this if this has something to do with encryption of data in transit with SSL.

Comment: I have updated my final observation in the question in the end. I also edited the question title. I am not deleting this question as it isn't downvoted by the community and I think, someone can still share their valuable remarks on this.